# Testing for equivalences of $\infty$-categories on strictifications?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

It is in general not too hard to show that maps between finite $CW$-complexes/finite simplicial sets are homotopy equivalences.

**Question** : Can we do something similar for:

- quasi-categorical equivalences between finite simplicial sets.
- "finitely generated" monoidal quasi-categories. Where by finitely generated I mean in a "polygraphic way" i.e. by a finite sequence of pushout of maps in the image of the free monoid functors.

and eventually more generally for $(\infty,2)$-categories or even $(\infty,n)$-categories.

I'll be more precise:

For homotopy equivalence between finite simplicial sets for example you have an explicit presentation of the $\pi_1$-groupoid given by the $0$,$1$-cell and $2$-cell. If the $\pi_1$ is equivalent to a set then Hurewicz's theorem tells you that you can test if your map is an equivalence on homology, and homology of finite simplicial sets is easy to compute.
If the $\pi_1$ are non trivial, it is a bit harder, but you can manage using the homology of the universal cover, or cohomology with value in local coefficient which are also very computable.

To some extent it also works for some infinite simplicial sets if they have explicit enough presentation.

Now I have a precise conjecture that would perfectly answer my question which I would details, but I'm also open to different suggestion.

The case of spaces above can be rephrased as follow:

**Theorem:** The strictification functor from weak $\infty$-groupoids to strict $\infty$-groupoids is conservative. (i.e. detect weak equivalences)

That might require some explanation.

Strict $\infty$-groupoids have been [proved by Brown and Higgins](http://www.numdam.org/article/CTGDC_1981__22_4_371_0.pdf) to be equivalent to "[Crossed complexes](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/crossed+complex)". And one can see that Crossed complexes are basically a structure that encodes a $\pi_1$ and what you need to compute a 'twisted' homology.

What I call the strictification functor, is in modern terms the left adjoint to the forgetful functor from strict $\infty$-groupoid to weak $\infty$-groupoid. Such a functor exists because there is a "Folk model structure" on the category of strict $\infty$-groupoids constructed by [Brown and Golanski](http://www.numdam.org/article/CTGDC_1989__30_1_61_0.pdf) meaning that the homotopy category of this model category is a cocomplete $(\infty,1)$-category and so there is a *unique* left adjoint functor from the $\infty$-category of space to the $\infty$-category of strict $\infty$-groupoid sending terminal object to terminal object.

And it basically corresponds to the construction sending a space to the crossed complex computing its $\pi_1$ and (co)homology (with local coefficient).

So similarly their should be a unique left adjoint functor from the category of $(\infty,n)$-categories to the  $\infty$-category of strict $(\infty,n)$-categories (the necessary model structure has been constructed by [Ara and Metayer](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.2599)) which send the first $n$ globes to the corresponding globes.

In the case of quasicategories such a functor can for example be constructed by taking the left Kan extension of [Street's Orientals](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/oriental), which gives a left adjoint functor from simplicial sets to strict $(\infty,1)$-categories, which I think is a Quillen functor for Joyal model structure and Ara-Metayer's folk structure on strict $(\infty,1)$-category.

**Conjecture**:The strictification functor from weak $(\infty,n)$-categories to strict $(\infty,n)$-categories is conservative.

The two case that are of main interest to me (and that corresponds to the first two points of my original question) is the case of the Kan extension of Street's Orientals from Joyal model structure to strict $(\infty,1)$-categories. And the conservativity of "the functor" from simplicial monoid (with quasi-categorical equivalences) to the category of "one object" $(\infty,2)$-categories (i.e. monoidal $\infty,1$-categories), which essentially corresponds to the second point of my initial question.

Comment: I have trouble believing your theorem.  Consider the 3-truncation of $S^2$, which has a fairly explicit presentation as a weak 3-groupoid generated by one 2-morphism, with the Hopf element in $\pi_3(S^2)$ arising from the braiding of this 2-morphism past itself.  Since the braiding in a strict 3-groupoid is trivial, it seems that this braiding must be trivialized in the strictification, which means that the strictification would not preserve $\pi_3$.  Hence, for instance, it would invert the noninvertible map $S^2 \to K(\mathbb{Z},2)$.  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @MikeShulman : Indeed, Being a "strict $\infty$-category" is not a property but a structure. If you have a strict $\infty$-category, see it as a weak $\infty$-category and applies the strictification functor to it you get a new, different $\infty$-category. If you beliebe that strictification exists and is left adjoint to the forgetful functor, You can easily see that the strictification functor will preserve $\pi_1$ and cohomology by observing the all $K(\pi,n)$ can be constructed as strict $\infty$-categories.

Comment: And if you spend a bit of time constructing the "twisted $K(\pi_1,G,n)$ for $G$ a $\pi_1$-module, which has $G$ as $\pi_n$, with the correct action of $\pi_1$ and $\pi_k=0$ for $k \neq 1,n$ as strict $\infty$-groupoids you get that strictification also preserves cohomology of local systems. which give a more explicit proof of the theorem.

Comment: Small correction: replace "strict $\infty$-category" by "strict $\infty$-groupoids" everywhere in my 1st comment... It is probably true that being a strict $\infty$-category is not a property, but I only know it for sure for "being an $\infty$-groupoid"

Comment: So what is wrong with my argument?

Comment: And can you give a citation for this theorem?

Comment: @SimonHenry Whatever strictification of $\infty$-categories means, I can give part of an argument that its conservativity follows from that of strictification for spaces. Cisinski proves in his recent book (and maybe it was already known) that the functor $C\mapsto (\mathrm{Core}(C),\mathrm{Core}(\mathrm{Arr}(C)))$ from $\infty$-categories to pairs of $\infty$-groupoids is conservative, which reduces the question to asking whether strictification commutes with taking the core of an $\infty$-category.

Comment: @MikeShulman : The (untruncated) $2$-sphere is freely generated by a $2$-cell $1_x \rightarrow 1_x$ so it is send to the free strict $\infty$-groupoid freely generated by a $2$-cell $1_x \rightarrow 1_x$, i.e. a $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$. But both $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ (as a weak $\infty$-groupoid) and the $3$-truncated $2$-sphere needs a lots of higher cells to be presented so they got send to more complicated $\infty$-groupoid. In fact one can show that a simply connected space get send to its homology complex (as crossed complex, i.e. a generalized Eilenberg MacLance space). I do not have a citation.

Comment: @KevinCarlson : Strictification is Left adjoint, so it does not interact well with taking the category of arrow or the core. Unless I'm missing something ?

Comment: I only brought in 3-truncatedness so I could talk about 3-groupoids, which I understand purely algebraically, instead of $\infty$-groupoids.  The 3-truncated 2-sphere is presented *as a 3-groupoid* by a single 2-cell.  Are you saying that the strictification of $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$ acquires nontrivial higher homotopy groups?  I guess I could see that as coming from its nontrivial cohomology; that would be an interesting perspective on the cohomology of Eilenberg-MacLane spaces.  But I would like to see this theorem written out and proven carefully.

Comment: @MikeShulman : Exactly: if you start from a simply connected space, like $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$, the $\pi_n$ of its strictification are its homology groups. This is relatively easy to prove: take a simplicial set model of the space with only one cell in dimension $1$ and $2$, and sent it to strict $\infty$-category using Street's Orientals. It lands in $\infty$-groupoids with only one objects and one $1$-cell, which are equivalent to the category of chains complex, and each Orientals get sent to the simplicial cohomology complex. But I don't know if this has been written properly somewhere

Comment: Guys, the theorem is just a 'modern' language restatement of Whitehead's theorem. A map is a homotopy equivalence if it induces a bijection on $\pi_0$, an isomorphism on $\pi_1$ for all possible basepoints, and on homology with local coefficients. The 'homology' of the crossed complex of a space is precisely that.

Comment: @FernandoMuro Maybe that (the fact that it is a restatement of Whitehead's theorem) seems obvious to you, but to me as a category theorist who doesn't "speak crossed complex", it is enormously surprising, although I'm starting to get the idea (thanks Simon).  Someone needs to write this out.

Comment: Let me point to my answer on an earlier question related to this: https://mathoverflow.net/a/225405/437 , which goes over some of the same ground.

Comment: I don't know where it's cleanly stated that the "strictification" functor does as what @FernandoMuro says it does.  But ultimately the observation is due to JHC Whitehead, who defined the original version of a functor $(\text{CW complexes})\to (\text{Crossed complexes})$.

Comment: I have made the following conjecture which extends @SimonHenry 's for groupoids , though perhaps not in print: the strictification functor $(\text{$\infty$-groupoids})\to (\text{strict $\infty$-groupoids})$ should be **comonadic**.  I suspect it's fairly provable: it would basically be the ultimate version of Mandell's theorem.

Comment: @MikeShulman just wanted to shed some light with a different perspective.

Comment: @SimonHenry Thanks. I don't see how the fact that strictification is a left adjoint makes it behave badly with core-there are certainly plenty of commuting squares of left and right adjoints in the world. But actually, your strictification functor seems to me to land in strict $\infty$-categories with *no* isomorphisms except the identities, so strictification badly fails to commute with core, while a map in an $\infty$-category looks to me to be invertible when its image in the strictification is *weakly* invertible. And shouldn't strictification factor through weak strictification, i.e...

Comment: ...a left adjoint to the inclusion of strict $\infty$-categories in which every map is weakly invertible into weak $\infty$-groupoids? Similarly, I can't see what goes wrong at a first glance with strictification and arrow categories, if the maps in the arrow category of a strict $\infty$-category are taken to be weakly commutative squares.

Comment: @KevinCarlson : Why you think that it lands in category with no isomorphisms ? this is justs not true: $1$-groupoids goes to themselves, $S^2$ goes to $K(\mathbb{Z},2)$... I mostly mean't that "it is not a right adjoint" so there are absolutely no reasons why it should commutes to arrow categories and/or core. If you think that is true I want to see a proof ! but I doubt it. It does factors through strict $\infty$-cat with weakly invertible arrows, but I don't see how this helps (in fact I think it is unknown if these two categories are different up to homotopy)

Comment: @SimonHenry There's also no general commutation of right adjoints with right adjoints, so I don't see how that would have helped with the core. Anyway-I may be misunderstanding, or being unclear about which strictification I mean where, but I don't see how a colimit of orientals allows for any strictly invertible 1-arrows. In the nerve of a 1-groupoid, a 2-simplex $(f,x,g)$ with degenerate middle face will get sent in the strictification to a nontrivial isomorphism between $x$ and $g\circ f$, no?

Comment: @KevinCarlson : These constructions takes values in strict $(\infty,n)$-categories even $(\infty,1)$ in the case you're talking about. so cells of dimension above $k$ are automatically invertible, and this then allows to make some cell of lower dimensions invertible as well. For this right adjoint business I just mean't that these constructions have "limit type" universal property so at least when you apply a right adjoint you still have a universal property. Here we are applying a functor that I only understand as "a left adjoint", so I have no idea what will happen with these constructions.